# D3 bar chart background with dots

Tags: d3.js

I found this d3 example showing a bar chart with a solid background and a diagonal line pattern. I'm trying to modify it to show dots, solid, white circles instead of lines, by modifying the 'd' attribute, but think there is probably a better way to do this.

This is my fiddle showing diagonal lines:

http://jsfiddle.net/ljp007/gruc1vod/1/

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

svg
  .append('defs')
  .append('pattern')
    .attr('id', 'diagonalHatch')
    .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
    .attr('width', 4)
    .attr('height', 4)
  .append('path')
    .attr('d', 'M-1,1 l2,-2 M0,4 l4,-4 M3,5 l2,-2')
    .attr('stroke', '#fff')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1);

svg.append("rect")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("width", 100)
      .attr("height", 100)
      .style("fill", 'blue');

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100)
    .attr('fill', 'url(#diagonalHatch)');
```

and here is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

The dots do not plot data but are simply for appearance to distinguish this bar from others in the chart. How can I convert the lines to dots to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of adding a path to your fill pattern add a couple of circles, and modify the size of the pattern slightly.

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

var pattern = svg.append('defs')
  .append('pattern')
    .attr('id', 'dots')
    .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
    .attr('width', 12)
    .attr('height', 12);

pattern.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', 2)
  .attr('cy', 2)
  .attr('r', 2)
  .attr('fill', 'white');

pattern.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', 8)
  .attr('cy', 8)
  .attr('r', 2)
  .attr('fill', 'white');

svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 100)
  .style("fill", 'blue');

svg.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 100)
  .attr('fill', 'url(#dots)');
```

The `cx` and `cy` attributes set the x and y co-ordinates of the centre of the circle, whilst the `r` attribute sets its radius.

You could also append a filled blue rectangle to the pattern before the circles to remove the need to create background and overlay rectangles in the chart.  You can add any basic shapes to a pattern and, when you use it to fill, they will be repeated along with their styling.

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

var pattern = svg.append('defs')
  .append('pattern')
    .attr('id', 'dots')
    .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
    .attr('width', 12)
    .attr('height', 12);

pattern.append('rect')
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', 0)
  .attr('width', 12)
  .attr('height', 12)
  .attr('fill', 'blue');

pattern.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', 2)
  .attr('cy', 2)
  .attr('r', 2)
  .attr('fill', 'white');

pattern.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', 8)
  .attr('cy', 8)
  .attr('r', 2)
  .attr('fill', 'white');

// Now the pattern can be used and re-used to fill any shapes.

svg.append('rect')
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('width', 100)
  .attr('height', 100)
  .attr('fill', 'url(#dots)');

svg.append('circle')
  .attr('cx', 160)
  .attr('cy', 50)
  .attr('r', 50)
  .attr('fill', 'url(#dots)');
```

Which gives:

[image: Example of Patterns]

Comment: I had almost the same idea but your answer is better explained. Upvoted.

Comment: @thibautg Thanks, I was feeling like a bit of a tool when I posted the answer and saw that you'd posted the same thing a few minutes before.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense now. Two rows of circles and two rectangles - one for the solid background color and one to overlay the two rows of circles.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to define a different svg element (a circle) inside your pattern definition. Here is one that is close to what you drew...

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

svg
  .append('defs')
  .append('pattern')
    .attr('id', 'dotFill')
    .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
    .attr('patternTransform', 'rotate(45)')
    .attr('width', 10)
    .attr('height', 10)
  .append('circle')
    .attr('cx', 5)
    .attr('cy', 5)
    .attr('r', 2)
    .attr('fill', '#fff')
    .attr('stroke', '#fff')
    .attr('stroke-width', 1);

svg.append("rect")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .attr("width", 100)
      .attr("height", 100)
      .style("fill", 'blue');

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100)
    .attr('fill', 'url(#dotFill)');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
svg
  .append('defs')
  .append('pattern')
    .attr('id', 'dotsPattern')
    .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
    .attr('width', 10)
    .attr('height', 10)
  .append('circle')
    .attr('cx', 5)
    .attr('cy', 5)
    .attr('r', 3)
    .style('fill', 'white');
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gruc1vod/4/)

Result:

[image: Dots]

Or an alternate style more similar to yours (requires two circles):

```
var pattern = svg
  .append('defs')
  .append('pattern')
    .attr('id', 'dotsPattern')
    .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
    .attr('width', 20)
    .attr('height', 20);
pattern.append('circle')
    .attr('cx', 5)
    .attr('cy', 5)
    .attr('r', 3)
    .style('fill', 'white');
pattern.append('circle')
    .attr('cx', 15)
    .attr('cy', 15)
    .attr('r', 3)
    .style('fill', 'white');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gruc1vod/5/)

Result:

[image: Dots with offset]